# Jest is not finding underscore

Tags: jestjs

I'm trying to test my project using `Jest` with following settings:

package.json:

```
{
  "jest": {
    "rootDir": "spec",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "testRegex": "spec/.*/*Spec.jsx?",
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/test-env.js"
    ],
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/(node_modules)/"
    ]
  }
}
```

And my `<rootDir>/test-env.js` contains:

```
global.$ = require("jquery");
global.jQuery = $;
global.React = require("react");
global.Backbone = require("backbone");
global.Backbone.$ = global.$;
global._ = require("underscore");
global.Q = require("q");
global.ReactTestUtils = require("react-addons-test-utils");
global.ReactDOM = require("react-dom");
```

But when I run `jest` to test it, it's reporting `Cannot read property '_' of undefined`.

[image: error message]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try requiring underscore before Backbone. Backbone requires the variable `_` to be presented in the global scope.

```
global._ = require("underscore");
global.Backbone = require("backbone");
...
```